# How to disable layout rendering for some action in espresso framework?

Tags: ruby, web-frameworks

I'm using `layout` to make all actions to render `:main` layout:

```
class Pages < E

  layout :main

  # actions that using layout

  # pager should not use layout
  def pager

  end
end
```

How to exclude `pager` from the list of actions that using layout?

I understand i can use this:

```
  setup :action_1, :action_2 do
    layout :main
  end
```

But when i have lot of actions it becomes hairy.

Comment: @Magicmarkker, nope, i tried this before asking :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set layout to `false` to disable it.

For your case use this:

```
setup :pager do
  layout false
end
```

Perhaps not really intuitive but it is done like this to avoid redundant options like `exclude`, `except`, `only` etc.

You also can skip setup and use `render_partial`:

```
  def pager
    render_partial # or render_p
  end
```

Comment: It works,Thank you. Regard intuitive, well, it is intuitive enough in Espresso context. I just have to accommodate a bit to new reality :)